# Querying a junction table using EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have several tables that I am trying to draw information from in as few queries as possible. I have a main table `timelineinfo`, two junction tables `junc_timelineinfo_officer` and `junc_timelineinfo_subject`, and two more tables `officer` and `subject`. Other than the name of the primary key Id, officer and subject are identical. My goal is to:

1. Given a date, get an id from the `timelineinfo` where the date matches
2. Use that id in the junction tables to find the matching `IdSubject` and `IdOfficer`
3. Use the `IdSubject`s and `IdOfficer`s to get the rows with those ids.

I have already done step one with the following code:

```cs
var Events = await _context.Timelineinfo.Where(t => t.Date.Equals(date)).ToListAsync();
```

Step two and three I think I've done with:

```cs
var SubjectIds = await _context.Junc_Timelineinfo_Subject
                    .Where(id => id.IdTimelineinfo.Equals(Event.IdTimelineInfo))
                    .Select(i => i.IdSubject)
                    .ToListAsync();
var OfficerIds = await _context.Junc_Timelineinfo_Officer
                     .Where(id => id.IdTimelineinfo.Equals(Event.IdTimelineInfo))
                     .Select(i => i.IdOfficer)
                     .ToListAsync();

//Step three
var Subjects = await _context.Subjects
                    .Where(i => i.IdSubject.Equals(SubjectIds))
                    .ToListAsync();
var Officers = await _context.Officers
                    .Where(i => i.IdOfficer.Equals(OfficerIds))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

But this is quickly getting clunky and using a bunch of queries. How can I simplify this to as few queries as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) for EF.
You need to define the relation / foreign key between your models first, either in your dbcontext or using [Data annotations](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) in your model

Then you can call the result like this:

```
var Events = await _context.Timelineinfo.Include(x => x.Subjects).Include(x => x.Officers).Where(t => t.Date.Equals(date)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I did some research on the use of includes in EF core, and it's my understanding that they query all the data from other tables first and then remove stuff according to where restrictions. This is much slower, and could build up quickly with more complex searches.